# dependent input field validations in jquery

Tags: validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate dependent inputs field , but i am n't getting any idea..

Suppose i have 3 fields named first_name, middle_name and age . If all the fields are empty or blank then it is ok, but when first field is filled then other two must required & validate properly... so how could i achieve this using jquery.
i am using jquery.js and jquery.validate.js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#frm").validate({
                rules:{
                    middle_name:{
            required: function(element) {
            return $('input[name="first_name"]').val() != '';
            }
                     }
                },
                messages:{
                      middle_name:{
                          required:"now it is mandatory.."
                },
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct to me - just to make explicit what you need to do try markup like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="required"/>
    <input type="text" name="middle_name" id="middle_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and you can use either a selector or a function as the value of a required parameter, I have used both below

```
$("form").validate({
    rules:{
        middle_name:{
            required:function(){
                 return $('input[name="first_name"]').val() != '';  
            }
        },
        last_name:{
            required:"#first_name:filled"
        }
    }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CcW3q/)